# "Simultaneous" requests generate new PHP session ID

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP script that dynamically generates JavaScript. I include it like you would include any external JS file (I use mod rewrite to give it a JS extension and I set the JS content header).

In certain cases, I want to be able to include this JS file multiple times on the same page (various different IDs are being passed through via the query string of the URL). Example:

```
<script src="script.js?id=3982"></script>
```

On the first page view, I've noticed that three unique sessions IDs are being generated (one for each request). It seems as though the last script to be included is the script that generates the final session ID that the user keeps. From there on, everything works fine.

Note: session_start() is included at the top of each script.

Comment: Well, yes, since the browser will attempt to load several scripts in parallel, and doesn't have a session cookie yet, it'll send off several id-less requests in parallel, which will all receive independent session ids. There's no real solution besides de-parallelising the requests. Meaning, include only *one* script which makes *one* initial connection to receive a cookie, then include the other scripts.

Comment: ...That, or some real bending-over-backwards in which the scripts include some stable id of their own (`script.js?id=3982&client_id=29321934`), and then use that to reconcile session ids on the backend.

Comment: @deceze Thank you! Paste that into an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Because it's not for user auth or anything, I might just hash the user agent and IP together or something.

Comment: You *will* get false positives if you depend on the IP, even if you additionally take the user agent into account.

Comment: @deceze How likely are these false positives?

Comment: Depends on your audience. Large corporations with many people using the same IT department-dictated browser behind the same NAT gateway are a big obvious example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, since the browser will attempt to load several scripts in parallel, and doesn't have a session cookie yet, it'll send off several id-less requests in parallel, which will all receive independent session ids. There's no real solution besides de-parallelising the requests. Meaning, include only *one* script which makes *one* initial connection to receive a cookie, then include the other scripts.